# Inserting large number (millions) of rows in a MySQL table using Eloquent in Laravel in a single HTTP Request

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Please note that I don't carry so much of experience.

The problem is well outlined in the question title and the logic follows below.

On my webapp there's a client who wants to engage with 'All' users of my webapp in the following ways -

- In-App Notifications (Will be pushed to Android App using RESTful APIs and Services)
- Emails - will be queued to a CRON job on my hosting.
- SMS - a third party RESTful api will do this job. Each call will send SMS to a single user.

Now assuming that my application grows, which obviously should, I'll be having say 50 Million users at some point in near future and the client on press of a button will request the application to send over notifications.

Considering, my client base grows too, say to around half a million, and there are atleast 50 clients doing this job of 'customer engagement' per second my server will have to send

- 50 * 50 million In-App notifications
- 50 * 50 million Emails
- 50 * 50 million SMS API calls

Since, API calls is out of context, let's take them off. We're now left with

- 50 * 50 million In-App notifications
- 50 * 50 million Emails

How I send notifications? A notification is sent by creating a new row in the notifications table with say userId and NotificationText.

How I send Emails? Using Laravel Queues with Database, the default Mail::queue function in Laravel does the job by creating a row in the 'jobs' table which is serviced by a CRON job.

Now, considering the above two cases I'll have to issue commands for creation of 50 * 50 * 2 Million MySQL rows in my database per second. This shall take considerable amount of time and each client shall wait for around x seconds to be redirected to a response page highlighting 'successful' request.

Is this approach relatively practical?

What value will x assume in this case?

The response will be delayed for some x seconds, is there a way to overcome this issue using Laravel Events?

During execution of the request (concurrently by many clients), is there a chance of increased resource usage leading to Denial of Service?

In case, the above mentioned approach is BAD, what alternative approach(es) do I have?

Comment: If they're sending to every user, why do you have to have to have an individual database record for each? Just code to assume it's going to all of them, then if you need to note that the notification has been seen, then create a record for that.

Comment: If the notifications only go to sections of your user base, then they will be presumably collected into categories, in which case you only have to make the association between the notification and the category, not with the individual users.

Comment: Extremely sorry to miss that out. Thanks anyways. But still, there's this Email thing.

Comment: Also, how can I mark the notification as read for a particular user. This will again need creation of separate rows in a separate table just for marking the notification as read since I have just one instance of notification for entire category of users.

Comment: Well yes, you'd need to reference that a notification was read by a user, but that would be a single database action, which would be far simpler than having to create an individual record for each user everytime a notification is sent. You may need to plan an additional layer to account for members who join after the notification is sent.

Comment: Your comments and the answer below has give me subtle ideas to implement the soluton. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For inserting data to the database you don't do 100M inserts but one insert using a sub-query, something like `INSERT INTO table (SELECT id, <message_id> FROM users);` where message_id can be set from your app so mysql see it as a constant. If this still take to much time you could look into having one table for messages to all as other have suggested and insert into the notification table when each user is reading the message.

For sending emails you could send it in bulk setting a large number of addresses as BCC, or use a service to send the emails so you avoid getting them marked as spam